# How to avoid Drush command not found after switching to aegir or other user?

Tags: drush, aegir

I installed Drush like this:

[image]

It works fine when I am `centos` user, when I switch user to `aegir` it doesn't work.

[image]

When I do `which drush` I get:

[image]

How can allow user `aegir` to use Drush?

Comment: Please QA-review the improvement I applied to your title ("not working* doesn't mean a lot, if anything ...). If you don't like it: just rollback, ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a symlink to let all user access drush.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/drush /usr/bin/
```

if not worked try

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/drush /usr/share/bin/
```

Comment: @NoSssweat you're welcome, I really getting happy when my help could safe other guys time. 